# С помощью какого модуля или какой возможности я могу строить графики заданных функций на Декартовой системе координат?

Tags: python, функции, математика

Я хочу построить(нарисовать графически) спираль Фибоначчи и другие функции на Декартовой плоскости.
Как я могу это сделать и как работать с графиками функций в `Python`?

Answer (score 4):

[matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/) и [NumPy](https://numpy.org/). Не скажу что это легко и просто, но сделать можно:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as patches


def rot(d):
    x, y = d
    return np.array((-y, x))


def squares(n):
    p = np.array([-1, 0])
    d1 = np.array([1, 0])
    d2 = np.array([0, -1])
    a = 0
    b = 1
    for _ in range(n):
        c = p + b * d1
        q = c + b * d2

        yield c, p, q

        p = q
        a, b = b, a + b
        d1 = rot(d1)
        d2 = rot(d2)


def atan2(v):
    x, y = v
    return np.arctan2(y, x)


def arc(c, p, q):
    a1 = atan2(p - c)
    a2 = atan2(q - c)
    if a2 < a1:
        a2 += 2 * np.pi
    theta = np.arange(a1, a2, 0.01)
    x = np.cos(theta)
    y = np.sin(theta)
    r = np.linalg.norm(p - c)
    cx, cy = c
    return r * x + cx, r * y + cy


def spiral(n):

    def gen():
        for c, p, q in squares(n):
            yield from zip(*arc(c, p, q))

    return tuple(zip(*gen()))


def polys(n):
    for c, p, q in squares(n):
        poly = patches.Polygon((c, p, p + q - c, q), closed=True, edgecolor='r', facecolor='none')
        r = round(np.linalg.norm(p - c))
        text = f'{r}x{r}' if r > 1 else ''
        label = text, (p + q) / 2
        yield poly, label


def main():
    n = 8
    s = spiral(n)

    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.plot(*s)
    for p, (t, l) in polys(n):
        ax.add_patch(p)
        ax.annotate(t, l, ha='center', va='center')
    ax.set_xticks([])
    ax.set_yticks([])
    plt.gca().set_aspect('equal', adjustable='box')
    plt.show()


main()
```

**P.S.** В коде четвертинки окружностей заданы точками. Это ошибка. В `matplotlib` есть возможность рисовать куски окружностей целиком. Я не стал её исправлять что бы в коде остался способ задания произвольных кривых.

Answer (score 3):

Начните с изучения `matplotlib`. Скорей всего это то, что нужно

[Здесь](https://matplotlib.org/) вы найдете документацию.

В связке с [numpy](https://numpy.org/).